# Running Exclamation Topology failed

Tags: apache-storm, nimbus, topology

~/src/storm-0.8.1/bin/storm jar /root/src/storm-starter/target/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology demo

**I tried to run this and it said that the problem is with the nimbus connection , but my storm client (and supervisor in the same time ) is connected with my nimbus (shown in Strom UI )**

Running: java -client -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/root/src/storm-0.8.1 -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -cp /root/src/storm-0.8.1/storm-0.8.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/carbonite-1.5.0.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/kryo-2.17.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/clout-0.4.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/clojure-1.4.0.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/ring-servlet-0.3.11.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/hiccup-0.3.6.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/disruptor-2.10.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/tools.cli-0.2.2.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/snakeyaml-1.9.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/joda-time-2.0.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/jzmq-2.1.0.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/clj-time-0.4.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/libthrift7-0.7.0.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/tools.logging-0.2.3.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/ring-core-0.3.10.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/ring-jetty-adapter-0.3.11.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/jgrapht-0.8.3.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/tools.macro-0.1.0.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/compojure-0.6.4.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/guava-13.0.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/curator-client-1.0.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/math.numeric-tower-0.0.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/junit-3.8.1.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/lib/zookeeper-3.3.3.jar:/root/src/storm-starter/target/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:/root/.storm:/root/src/storm-0.8.1/bin -Dstorm.jar=/root/src/storm-starter/target/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology demo Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.(NimbusClient.java:36) at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:17) at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:53) at storm.starter.ExclamationTopology.main(ExclamationTopology.java:59) Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183) at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81) at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.(NimbusClient.java:34) ... 3 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:178)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to suggest that you are having trouble connecting to nimbus from the machine where you are trying to run this command from. Most likely there is something wrong in your `~/.storm/storm.yaml`. Make sure you have this [correctly configured](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Setting-up-development-environment) to point to your nimbus server.

Comment: the server I'm trying to run this command from is the same where i'm running my supervisor , so there is a connection between the two servers.
here's what I have in my storm.yaml : 
 storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx6"
#     - "server2"
#
 nimbus.host: "xx.xxx.xxx.xx6"